# Continuity of $T \mapsto \pi_{\operatorname{ker}T}$ w.r.t. the SOT

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

I came across the following technical question, to which I could not - after some time of thinking - find an answer:

Let $\mathcal{U},\mathcal{H}$ be two real (in general infinite dimensional) separable Hilbert spaces. For some linear subspace $\bar{U} \subseteq \mathcal{U}$, let $\Pi_U$ denote the orthogonal projection on this subspace. The question is:

Is the mapping $T \mapsto \Pi_{\operatorname{ker}T}$ continuous from $L(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{H})$ to $L(\mathcal{U})$ when both spaces are endowed with the strong operator topology?

Any hints and thoughts on this are more than appreciated!

Comment: It is bad practice on this site to edit your question to ask something different once you have received an answer. You should ask a new question instead. I have rolled back your edit so the question is in its original form.

Comment: Thanks for the hint & sorry for that!

Comment: Note the typographical difference between \text{ker} T and \operatorname{ker} T : $\text{ker} T \text{ versus } \operatorname{ker}T.$ With operatorname, the amount of space to its left and right depends on context, thus: $\operatorname{ker}(T)$ has less space to its right than does $\operatorname{ker}T.$ I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample take $\mathcal{U} = \mathcal{H} = \mathbb{R}$ and let $T_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $T_n x = \frac{x}{n}$. Then $T_n \to 0$ in the strong operator topology (and in fact even in operator norm). However $\ker T_n = \{0\}$ for all $n$ so for every $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ we have that $0 = \Pi_{\ker T_n} x \not \to \Pi_{\ker 0}x = x$.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you! Certainly an easy and convincing example. Maybe there is a chance to get a weaker statement (which could still be sufficient for my case): Is the mapping measurable (with both Borel-$\sigma$-algebras being generated by the SOT)?